# Conditionally change color of angularjs element?

Tags: css, angularjs, conditional-statements

Im still pretty new to AngularJS. Im trying to change the color of the table element so that its yellow if the user voted on this choice.

```
<div ng-show="poll.userVoted">
    <table class="result-table">
        <tr ng-repeat="choice in poll.choices">
            <td>{{choice.text}}</td>
            <td>
            <table ng-if="choice.text == poll.userChoice.text" style="background-color: yellow; width: {{choice.votes.length/poll.totalVotes*100}}%; text-align: right">
                <tr>

                        <td>{{choice.votes.length}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table ng-if="choice.text != poll.userChoice.text" style="background-color: lightblue; width: {{choice.votes.length/poll.totalVotes*100}}%; text-align: right">
                <tr>

                    <td>{{choice.votes.length}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

[image]

Comment: You can try something like this, if I understand your question title correctly  - http://plnkr.co/edit/jeszGorMQmLiqhtWDt94?p=preview

Comment: thanks i will prob do it something like this. i just thought i could do it in tags somehow without making a function for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is done by using ng-class.

Use ng-class on your td like this:

```
<td ng-class="{yellowstyle: choice.text==poll.userChoice.text}">...</td>
```

that will put the css class yellowstyle on the item when your condition is true.

And in your example:

```
<table class="result-table">
  <tr ng-repeat="choice in poll.choices">
    <td>{{choice.text}}</td>
    <td>
      <table style="width: {{choice.votes.length/poll.totalVotes*100}}%; text-align: right">
        <tr>
          <td ng-class="{yellowstyle: choice.text==poll.userChoice.text, lightbluestyle: choice.text!=poll.userChoice.text}">{{choice.votes.length}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

with a style.css file that has:

```
.yellowstyle {background-color: yellow;}
.lightbluestyle {background-color: lightblue;}
```

Comment: this gives me a syntax error:
`Error: Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 12 of the expression [yellowstyle: choice.text==poll.userChoice.text, lightbluestyle: choice.text!=poll.userChoice.text] starting at [: choice.text==poll.userChoice.text, lightbluestyle: choice.text!=poll.userChoice.text].`

Comment: Sorry forgot the {} in ng-class, fixed, try again