# Changing Color for each card using angularjs ng-class

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css, ng-class

I have used this example in my project to change colors of specific data in response which i am using in ng-repeat. But i Got a error.. 
[Conditionally change color of angularjs element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093075/conditionally-change-color-of-angularjs-element)

The Error Which i am facing is

```html
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$parse/syntax?p0=Backs&p1=is%20unexpected…%3D%3D'CallBacks'%2Ccard_media_followup%3ACall%20Backs%3D%3D'Followups'%7D
    at Error (native)
    at file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:6:416
    at Object.s.throwError (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:210:32)
    at Object.s.consume (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:210:207)
    at Object.s.object (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:209:448)
    at Object.s.primary (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:206:335)
    at Object.s.unary (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:206:174)
    at Object.s.multiplicative (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:205:434)
    at Object.s.additive (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:205:261)
    at Object.s.relational (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:205:96) <md-card-title-media ng-class="{card_media_prosp:{{s.svStatus}}=='Prospective',card_media_na:{{s.svStatus}}=='NotInterested',
  card_media_closed:{{s.svStatus}}=='Closed',card_media_callback:{{s.svStatus}}=='CallBacks',card_media_followup:{{s.svStatus}}=='Followups'}">(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:107
2angular.min.js:107 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$parse/syntax?p0=Interested&p1=is%20unexp…3D'CallBacks'%2Ccard_media_followup%3ANot%20Interested%3D%3D'Followups'%7D
    at Error (native)
    at file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:6:416
    at Object.s.throwError (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:210:32)
    at Object.s.consume (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:210:207)
    at Object.s.object (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:209:448)
    at Object.s.primary (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:206:335)
    at Object.s.unary (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:206:174)
    at Object.s.multiplicative (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:205:434)
    at Object.s.additive (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:205:261)
    at Object.s.relational (file:///android_asset/www/js/angular.min.js:205:96) <md-card-title-media ng-class="{card_media_prosp:{{s.svStatus}}=='Prospective',card_media_na:{{s.svStatus}}=='NotInterested',
  card_media_closed:{{s.svStatus}}=='Closed',card_media_callback:{{s.svStatus}}=='CallBacks',card_media_followup:{{s.svStatus}}=='Followups'}">(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:107
```

```
The error is
```

```html
Syntax Error: Token 'Backs' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 24 of the expression [{card_media_prosp:Call Backs=='Prospective',card_media_na:Call Backs=='NotInterested',
  card_media_closed:Call Backs=='Closed',card_media_callback:Call Backs=='CallBacks',card_media_followup:Call Backs=='Followups'}] starting at [Backs=='Prospective',card_media_na:Call Backs=='NotInterested',
  card_media_closed:Call Backs=='Closed',card_media_callback:Call Backs=='CallBacks',card_media_followup:Call Backs=='Followups'}].
```

HTML Page->

```html
 <md-card class="md-primary" style="background-color:#FBC02D;">
             <md-card-title style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px !important">
      <md-card-title-media ng-class="{card_media_prosp:      {{s.svStatus}}=='Prospective',card_media_na:{{s.svStatus}}=='Not Interested',
  card_media_closed:{{s.svStatus}}=='Closed',card_media_callback:{{s.svStatus}}=='Call Backs',card_media_followup:{{s.svStatus}}=='Followups'}">
    <div class="card_status">{{s.svStatus | limitTo:1 }}</div>
  </md-card-title-media>

    <md-card-title-text class="card_content">
      <span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight:bold">{{s.svID}} {{s.svCompanyName}}</span>
      <span class="md-subhead">POC: {{s.svOwnName}}</span>
      <span class="md-subhead">Phone: {{s.svContactNo}}</span>
    </md-card-title-text>

             </md-card-title>
           </md-card>
```

```css
.card_media_prosp {
  background-color: #00e6ac;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      width: 15%;
      margin-top: 0px;
}
.card-media_new {
  background-color: #00e6ac;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      width: 15%;
      margin-top: 0px;
}
.card_media_callback {
  background-color:#4d4dff ;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      width: 15%;
      margin-top: 0px;
}
.card_media_followup {
  background-color: #cc8400;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      width: 15%;
      margin-top: 0px;
}
.card_media_na {
  background-color:#fd2d2c;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      width: 15%;
      margin-top: 0px;
}
.card_media_closed {
  background-color: #a6a6a6;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      width: 15%;
      margin-top: 0px;
}
 .card_status{
  margin-top: 25%;
  margin-left: 25%;
   font-size: 2em;
 }
```

I don't know exactly what to do to finish this error, can you please suggest some explanation or some example how to change specific colors for each card data by using some item in response... Thanks in advance guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `{{}}` to compare with your string. just compare without `{{}}`. just use `s.svStatus` instead of `{{s.svStatus}}`

like:

```
ng-class="{card_media_prosp:s.svStatus=='Prospective',card_media_na:s.svStatus=='Not Interested' ....}"
```

**or**

you can try by `'{{s.svStatus}}'` instead of `{{s.svStatus}}` means use  `{{}}` in single quotation `('')` so use `'{{}}'`

like:

```
ng-class="{card_media_prosp:'{{s.svStatus}}'=='Prospective',card_media_na:'{{s.svStatus}}'=='Not Interested' ....}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ng-class="{card_media_prosp: s.svStatus=='Prospective',card_media_na:s.svStatus=='Not Interested', card_media_closed:s.svStatus=='Closed', card_media_callback:s.svStatus=='Call Backs', card_media_followup:s.svStatus=='Followups'}
```

Complete html:

```
<md-card class="md-primary" style="background-color:#FBC02D;">
         <md-card-title style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px !important">
  <md-card-title-media ng-class="{card_media_prosp: s.svStatus=='Prospective',card_media_na:s.svStatus=='Not Interested',
     card_media_closed:s.svStatus=='Closed', card_media_callback:s.svStatus=='Call Backs', card_media_followup:s.svStatus=='Followups'}">
<div class="card_status">{{s.svStatus | limitTo:1 }}</div>
</md-card-title-media>
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-class syntax should be as below, you don't have to interpolate {{}} the expressions of the scope

```
ng-class="{'class1' : expression1, 'class2':expression1 ... }"

ng-class="{card_media_prosp:s.svStatus=='Prospective',card_media_na:s.svStatus=='Not Interested',    card_media_closed:s.svStatus=='Closed',card_media_callback:s.svStatus=='Call Backs',card_media_followup:s.svStatus=='Followups'}"
```

refer:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass